# How do I prepend or insertbefore this form value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following:

```
<input type="text" class="example" id="number" readonly="readonly" value="blue widget" name="widget"></input>
```

I would like to use javascript/jquery to make the value "large blue widget"

so I need prepend or insert before, or something, but I don't know how to target just the value of class "example"

Comment: And `input` doesn't have a closing tag, it's self-closing: `<input />` *not* `<input></input>`.

Comment: hmmm...see this is coming from an off site script I am calling, so I am trying to clean up some of the junk it comes over with, plus add to the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JQuery you can change value of input boxes with [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

You can use *class selector*:

```
$(".example").val("large blue widget");
```

Or you can use *selector by ID*:

```
$("#number").val("large blue widget");
```

To prepend text you can use:

```
$(".example").val(function(index, text) {
    return "large " + text;
});
```

Comment: +1 for that last example - function version of `.val` is perfect for read/modify/write

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to access and update the value of an input field

```
var currentValue = $('.example').val();
$('.example').val("large " + currentValue);
```